# How to find limit of $\lim_{x \to \infty} a_n$, where $a_{n+1}= \sin a_n$

Tags: limits

The answer shows that

- let $\lim a_n=A$
- since $a_{n+1}= \sin a_n$, adding limit both side will get $A= \sin A$.

But how does it works?

I guess $A= \lim a_n =\lim \sin a_n \neq \sin \lim a_n = \sin A$

What did I miss?

Comment: Try to use Lamerey diagram

Comment: @TimurBakiev Sorry, I cannot understand Lamerey diagram. I never learnt this. I searched and guess it is a method of ploting and analysing the diagram. But I think I do need a serious proof.

Comment: Why do you have a not-equal sign in your guess? (The answer you've accepted explicitly "commutes" lim and sin in its key step.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sin(x)$ is continuous and defined everywhere, we know that if $b_n$ is a sequence and $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n = b$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(b_n) = \sin\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n\right) = \sin(b)$.

So, if $a_{n+1}=\sin(a_n)$, then we know that **if** $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists and equals $A$, then
$$\begin{align*}
A &= \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin(a_n)\\
&= \sin\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n\right)\\
&= \sin(A).
\end{align*}$$
Of course, this assumes that you already know that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists.

In fact, one can prove that, regardless of the value of $a_1$, the sequence defined by $a_1=k$, $a_{n+1}=\sin(a_n)$ for all $n\geq 1$, will converge. Say it converges to $A$; then, as above, we get that $\sin(A)=A$. Since this means $-1\leq A\leq 1$, and since the function $g(x) = x-\sin(x)$ has $g'(x) = 1-\cos(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$ in $[-1,1]$, equal to $0$ only at $x=0$, the function is strictly increasing on $[-1,1]$; thus, $g(x)=0$ has only one solution on $[-1,1]$, which is at $x=0$, and so we will conclude, once we prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists, that in fact $A=0$.

Comment: That make sense. Thank you very much!

Comment: I find one way but yours must be more brief! I dont need to use Heine Therom and the last sentence warns me the limitation. Thanks very much!

Comment: @scbz: In fact, one can prove the limit exists regardless of what $a_1$ is; and then it follows that since the limit must satisfy $A=\sin(A)$, it is necessarily the case that $A=0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $\sin(a_1)=0$ then obvioulsy $a_n=0$ for all $n\geq 2$.

Otherwise, let $a_2=\sin(a_1)\in[-1,1]\setminus\{0\}$:

- If $\sin(a_1)\in(0,1]$, then $a_{n+1}\in(0,1]$ and $a_{n+1}\leq a_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. The proof for this is easy. Assume it's true for $n-1$. Then $a_{n}\in(0,1]\subset(0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, so $a_{n+1}=\sin(a_n)\in(0,1]$. Also, because of the famous inequality $|\sin(x)|\leq |x|$ you have $a_{n+1}=\sin(a_n)\leq a_n$. Then $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is decreasing and bounded.
- Analogously you can prove that if $\sin(a_1)\in[-1,0)$, then $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a increasing and bounded sequence.

In any case $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is an monotone bounded sequence, so it must converge.  Let $l:=\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$. Because of the convergence of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}-a_n=\sin{a_n}-a_n=0$.  Then $\sin(l)=l$, which implies $l=0$.

Comment: Oh that's great! I'm sorry I didnt post the limitation that $x \in (0, \pi)$, but this bring the idea further! Before suppose $\lim =A$, it is important to assure it is convergent!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the hints:

- Heine Theorem
- if function continuous, $\lim f(x) = f(\lim x)$

where the latter one is easy to proove by definition.